# Linking MKL in catkin_make / Cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, eigen, intel-mkl, catkin

I have a large codebase with multiple files and multiple Cmake files as well. The structure is `src/folder1 src/folder2` etc and I run `catkin_make -j1` from the src directory level. I am unable to link MKL. A small clip of the error is

```
/usr/bin/ld: /opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2021.3.0/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so: undefined reference to `mkl_sparse_d_xESB_SpMV_8_i4'
/usr/bin/ld: /opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2021.3.0/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so: undefined reference to `mkl_spblas_zcoo0ssunc__mmout_par'
/usr/bin/ld: /opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2021.3.0/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so: undefined reference to `mkl_spblas_zcoo1ntuuf__mmout_par'
/usr/bin/ld: /opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2021.3.0/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so: undefined reference to `mkl_spblas_lp64_scsr0ntunc__smout_par'
/usr/bin/ld: /opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2021.3.0/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so: undefined reference to `mkl_spblas_lp64_ccsr0nd_nc__svout_seq'
/usr/bin/ld: /opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2021.3.0/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so: undefined reference to `mkl_spblas_ccoo1stlnf__svout_seq'
/usr/bin/ld: /opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2021.3.0/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so: undefined reference to `mkl_pds_pds_her_pos_fwd_ker_seq_nrhs_cmplx'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I even added the following line to each cmake:

```
  SET(GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS    " -L${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64 -Wl,--no-as-needed -lmkl_intel_ilp64 -lmkl_gnu_thread -lmkl_core -lgomp -lpthread -lm -ldl")
```

The code does not use MKL BLAS directly but rather it is used by libraries like Opencv and Eigen (OpenCV was built with MKL).

I do define `EIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL`.

How do I link MKL?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of oneMKL link line advisor which recommends what are the required libraries and necessary compiler options for the use case on which you are working.
Here is the link
https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/oneapi/components/onemkl/link-line-advisor.html